# Connection to a private k8s cluster: failed to find any PEM

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster which is running in a private cloud. I want to run some commands from another VM but I receive this:

```
[root@runner-tmp ~]# kubectl get pods --kubeconfig local-cluster.yaml
error: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input
```

My local-cluster.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://x.x.x.x:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: FSM
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Do you have any idea where should I specify this PEM certificate and how can I generate it?

Comment: [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6140924) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69502581) saying "Not sure if you found the answer yet, but I have my own k8s cluster and recently had to solve for this. Please follow the steps here: [https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#normal-user](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#normal-user)"